# Pandoc "--filter" option is not working with "comments.py" script

Tags: python, pandoc

I'm trying to use the 'comments.py' script (from repository [github.com/aaren/pandocfilters](https://github.com/aaren/pandocfilters/blob/master/examples/comments.py)) with the following command:

```
Pandoc -o myOutput.tex myInput.html --filter ./comments.py
```

but it is not working.

Pandoc always converts text that is between the tags `<!-- BEGIN COMMENT -->` and `<!-- END COMMENT -->` and remove the comments.

Could someone help me figure out what is the problem?

PS: I tested 'caps.py' script (from the same repo) and it worked fine, but 'comments.py' doesn't.

I need to ignore the text between specified tag.

This is my HTML input:

```
<i> normal text </i> 

<!-- BEGIN COMMENT -->

<i> ignore this line </i> 

<!-- END COMMENT -->

<b> normal text 2 </b>
```

And this is my LaTeX output:

```
\emph{normal text} 

\emph{ignore this line} 

\textbf{normal text 2}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the filter doesn't work is because when Pandoc reads HTML, it doesn't take comments with it. On the other hand when Pandoc reads Markdown, it stores the comments in its AST as `RawBlock 'html'`.

So you need to use the filter with markdown input, like:

```
normal text

<!-- BEGIN COMMENT -->

ignore this line

<!-- END COMMENT -->

normal text 2
```

```
pandoc -o myOutput.tex myInput.md --filter ./comments.py
```

Or just use plain HTML comments instead:

```
<i> normal text </i> 

<!--

<i> ignore this line </i> 

-->

<b> normal text 2 </b>
```

Comment: mb21, thanks for replying. It is a good idea, I'll do some tests.
However my input (including the content of comments) needs to be html and the output (except the content of comments) needs to be latex.